# Displaying the latest posts from a custom field group

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this custom Metabox field group from https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#group containing 3 fields and displayed on the Products page template, i want to call the latest posts the client add to display them on my front-page. here is the code of the custom fields.

```js
/**
  * Repeatable Field Groups
  */
 $meta_boxes['field_group'] = array(
  'id'           => 'field_group',
  'title'        => __( 'Manage your products here', 'cmb2' ),
  'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 11, ) ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
  'object_types' => array( 'page', ),
  'fields'       => array(
   array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'repeat_group',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'options'     => array(
     'group_title'   => __( 'Product {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
     'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Product', 'cmb2' ),
     'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Product', 'cmb2' ),
     'sortable'      => true, // beta
    ),
    'fields'      => array(
     array(
      'name' => 'Product Name',
      'id'   => 'product_name',
      'type' => 'text',
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'Product Description',
      'description' => 'Write a short description for this Product',
      'id'   => 'product_description',
      'type' => 'textarea',
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'Product Image',
      'id'   => 'product_image',
      'type' => 'file',
     ),
    ),
   ),
  ),
 );
```

UPDATE:
i found this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts but i still can't figure out how to make it get the posts from the custom fields

Comment: Someone likes their tabs!

Comment: @dwhite.me i am not following you !